# JSON serialization of C char array (char*)

Tags: c, json, serialization, json-serialization

Is it possible to encode a C char array (char*) in JSON in order to send it through a TCP socket? If so how can I make it and which would be a simple JSON library to use?

Thanks,

Comment: Why would you need to encode a `char` array in JSON? Just send the length and the bytes.

Comment: JSON is not a transfer protocol, it is a data format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't need to use JSON. If you just want to send a simple message (e.g. "Hi, how are ya"), then you can just send the char array. You cannot send JSON, only a char array of JSON (JSON is a data format, not a transfer protocol).
Example

```
const char *json = "{\"id\": 12837, \"name\": \"Massimo Isonni\"}"
// You would then send json.
```

If you need to serialize a struct into a JSON string, I would recommend [this](https://github.com/json-c/json-c).